# GZip Compression in tomcat7 not working in IE9

Tags: performance, internet-explorer, tomcat, tomcat7, gzip

I am using the below code in my server.xml file. It is working fine in firefox, where the response size was very much reduced. 200kb -> 25kb. But, not working in IE9. Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

```
 <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"
       maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
           maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
           enableLookups="false" acceptCount="100"
           disableUploadTimeout="true" 
           compression="on" compressionMinSize="2048" 
     noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata" 
     compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript,text/json,application/x-javascript,application/javascript,application/json"    
/>
```

Comment: Take a look at the HTTP headers IE is sending with a tool such as ieHTTPHeaders

Comment: @MarkThomas - When i viewed the request header in IE using IE dev toolbar, In the accept-encoding, it is showing as gzip,deflate.

Answer (score 1):

Compression only happens if the user-agent wants it in that way.

When a user-agent makes a request it need to send its preference of compress though Accept-Encoding header.

```
accept-encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
```

Only when this header is sent as part of the web request the web server will enable compression for the content that is sent. You can test it using curl

```
curl -L http://localhost/index.jsp -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' -o - | gzip
```

The above will generate a compressed data which can be uncompressed using gzip.

Mostly in your case it looks like IE is not preferring to get the content of the page as compressed and not sure why this happens.

Comment: hi kannan, When i viewed the request header in IE, in the accept-encoding, it is showing as gzip,deflate. But, in the response section, gzip not gets enabled where as it gets enabled in firefox.

Comment: Can you paste the complete request and response header of IE.